# Getting error after running php artisan cache:clear Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After running `php artisan cache:clear`

I am getting error:

> Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)

Comment: What is your **php version** and **laravel framework version** ?

Comment: php 7.1 & laravel 5.8

Comment: Please attach your `composer.json` file in question

Answer (score 3):

i got the same error

i solved it  by add

```
"symfony/translation": "4.3.8"
```

to my composer.json file

and then run 
`composer update`

every thing work good after that

Comment: Use this only if you can't upgrade your php version

Answer (score 1):

PHP version (7.1) has been unsupported for 11 days ago(1 Dec 2019) : [LINK](https://www.php.net/eol.php)

Solution: Update your PHP with the latest version

Comment: Try it @Ranjeet

Comment: what happened @Ranjeet? Did problem solve or still facing error?

Answer (score 1):

Do below changes-

1. `"symfony/translation": "4.3.8"` in your `composer.json`,
2. run `composer update`